# fatal: unable to access 'H:\/.config/git/config': Invalid argument [Git on Windows 7]

Tags: git, windows-7

I get this error when opening a git repository:

fatal: unable to access 'H:/.config/git/config': Invalid argument

Where in git is this path being pulled from?

'H:/.config/git/config'

I found some articles that it might be the "Home" or "UserProfile" environment variables but in my case the "Home" variable is not created and the "UserProfile" is not pointing to that path.  So where is git getting that path from?

Comment: How did you find that HOME is not set?

Answer (score 23):

I experienced a similar issue when not connected to my work network via VPN.   Running the following from a command window worked for me:

```
net use H: /delete
```

This command actually deleted the H drive. If you actually use the mapped drive that is causing the issue, then this way could cause you other problems that would only be solved by remapping the drive (net use H:, followed by the mapped drive path).  As a note, I did delete the HOME% variables (using "set HOME=" from the command line), but it did work until the command above was run.

Comment: I had the similar issue. When connected to VPN, everything is OK. When not, I see the same error.

Comment: So if you're back on your work VPN you need to reconnect to the network drive again? Is there an alternative, less heavy handed solution?

Answer (score 12):

A lot of solutions were presented. Conclusion: The problem is a remote HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE environmental variable and appears when you are not connected to your network.

IMHO the solution with **no side-effects** (when your HOME variable is not set) is setting your HOME environmental variable of your profile to an existing ***local*** path.

First check if HOME is set or not. Open cmd.exe (Command prompt) and type

```
set HOME
```

If you do not get a result, just for HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE, than HOME is NOT set. Go to control panel:

Press WIN-R and then type `control`. Go to users profiles and you find a link on the left sidebar to change the environmental variable of your profile. The rest should be self-explanatory. Add variable `HOME` with path e.g. `c:\users\myprofile`.

With this attempt you could let HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE untouched and get no side-effects when reconnected to your network.

Worked for me.

*IMPORTANT:* But you lose your git settings. So you have to copy at least `.gitconfig` from your remote network home drive to your new local HOME directory before you disconnect from your network.

Thanks to Navjot Bhardwaj and VonC.

Comment: Well done, setting your user environment variable. +1

Answer (score 9):

My situation was that I ran `git checkout <branch>` and I had `fatal: unable to access 'H://.gitconfig': Invalid argument`. Then I run `set HOME` and had no results.
The following steps solved the issue

1. (! skip the first time) change SSH keys
2. (! skip the first time) restart the computer
3. find .gitconfig (should be in the root of H:// or whatever drive name you have)
4. open it with Notepad++ (or other editor) and save as it is. If it is empty, then save empty one
5. then `git checkout master` started working

If it happned once again, I would start from step 3 :-)

Comment: Steps 3 and 4 only were enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: 3 & 4 worked for me

Answer (score 5):

net delete is not a must.

First check HOME setting, then change HOME and HOMEDRIVE to a existing dir.

```
c:\git\selenium-automation>set HOME
HOME=U:\
HOMEDRIVE=U:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\XX
```

then change HOME and HOMEDRIVE by

```
set HOME=c:\tmp
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
```

c:\git\selenium-automation>set HOME

```
HOME=c:\tmp
HOMEDRIVE=c:
HOMEPATH=\
HOMESHARE=\\XX
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure, in a command line window:

- `HOME` is indeed not set: type `set HOME`, which would return its value if any
- the issue persists with the [latest msysgit distribution](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) (1.9.0): unzip that archive anywhere, and call git with its full path:

  ```
  c/mydir/PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217/bin/git.exe --global -l
  ```

Comment: Git seems to look for HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE, too.

Comment: @andig it should look only at `HOME`. But then again `HOME` is defined as `HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/d8402fb5e72c91aafea8592b867cbcf8880cb7c1/git-cmd.bat#L9)

Answer (score 4):

Set HOME var in 'User variable for ' (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\ => Advanced system settings\Advanced\Env variables)

It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

May be this will help some one who is on windows 10.

Assuming if you have network drive and you are facing the above error

Step 1: Hit windows key and type `Environment Variables`

Step 2: In the Advanced > Under startup and recovery > environment variables > Under 'variables section`
Step 3: Specify your path like below.

This will definitely work even for source tree or actual git problem. Thanks

[image]

Comment: In my Case, my remote drive file was not accessible. 
Do above step. than to recreate git files do below steps on existing repo or check new repo.
refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Answer (score 2):

If you'll check your GIT installation path /git/etc/profile you'll see HOME variable set as: 
 
HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH" 
For this I created HOME variable in my Environment variables and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

As some people are saying this seems to be an issue with HomeDrive and HomePath when using network drives.

For me this was solved by running my git commands as admin.

Comment: I also got this error: fstat on H://.gitconfig failed: Invalid argument                                                             For me this was solved by running my git commands as admin.