# How to correctly add 'git push' command to crontab - Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, cron

I believe it's a simple question, but I've added a folder as `Origin Master` just as [this guide oriented](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

I created a file `backupgit.cron` and inside it the following commands:

```
cd /var/bkpfolder/
git add .
git commit -m "another commit"
git push origin master
```

And at `crontab -e` I included the line bellow:

```
30 * * * * /var/bkpfolder/backupgit.cron
```

The thing is, the (new) files I add to test this crontab are never uploaded... If i run the commands at the `backupgit.cron` manually they do work.

I believe that it's something to do with the going to the `origin master` folder (`cd /var/bkpfolder/`?) to execute the push command, so what I'm looking for is **a correct way to execute the push commands to the `/bkpfolder/`** stated in the `backupgit.cron`

thanks in advance!

Comment: A few things... First and most important: capture the output from the cron job. Seeing any error output will be critical to diagnosing. Second, are you sure of what you're doing? Having a cron job do `git add .` seems very dangerous to me. Lastly, it's not clear what you mean about "setting up an origin master folder"? Origin is (usually) a remote; master is (usually) a branch. A folder is neither of these things. Maybe it would help to know what steps from the linked document you mean to be following.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger  ,everything that folder will have are the files I need to push. I did all the steps the link I provided stated and the only way I managed to push was following all the steps I stated are inside the `backupgit.cron`. I don't have to follow those exact steps, if there is another way to push all files added to that folder periodically that's the solution for me.

Comment: Is your origin `Master` as metioned in the first sentence or `master` as mentioned in the script? Maybe it is only a typo?

Comment: just `master`..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out what I was doing wrong... As I stated, the commands inside the `backupgit.cron` worked when I was inside the folder (read as not the default folder crontab is)... So I just figured out that at the beggining of the `git`command I can specify my folder of action as in `git -C /var/bkpfolder/`

So I replaced what was inside of the `backupgit.cron` **from:**

```
cd /var/bkpfolder/
git add .
git commit -m "another commit"
git push origin master
```

**To:**

```
git -C /var/bkpfolder/ add .
git -C /var/bkpfolder/ commit -m "another commit"
git -C /var/bkpfolder/ push origin master
```

**+**

Added permissions to read/write the file a the user the crontab was written to

Comment: check out my example. you do not need to add `-C /var/bkpfolder`.

Comment: your solution only worked for me when I was inside the new 'main_backup'... it didn't work at cron unless I specified the folder with the `-C`command :/

Comment: But for me, it miss the passphrase handling

Comment: @Mahefa, I believe you can store your git credentials for the user.. After signing in, try this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: @mrbTT > Thanks. I have removed the passphrase cause I can. I will try this when I have a case where I can't remove passphrase

Answer (score 0):

Your origin `master` has to be either a bare-repository or the branch may not be checked out.

If it is not a bare-repository and the branch which will be pushed is checked out, you will get the following error:

```
git push origin master --force
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 214 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote:
remote: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote:
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /Users/Roman/gittest/master
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/Users/Roman/gittest/master'
```

### Solution

If you do not want to use a bare-repository, you have to checkout a branch that differs between your `bkpfolder` and your `master`-directory.

### Out of the box example

For better undestanding i renamed the remote `master` to `origin`.

```
mkdir main_backup
cd main_backup && git init --bare && cd ..
git clone main_backup bkpfolder
cd bkpfolder && echo "This is a test" >> test.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'Automatic backup'
git push origin master
```

Comment: The command `git push origin master` only works if I'm inside the `/var/bkpfolder/`, I'm not sure I follow what I'm intended to do... consider that I'm not a git expert, I just received an url that I've set as `remote repository` while I was at the `bkpfolder`.

Comment: `bkpfolder` is the folder you want to backup and you want to push the changes to your `master` directory which is the remote `origin`.

Comment: Right... and how do I do that?