# Insert string into input request Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to make a PS script for checking out my Dev branch and pulling the latest commits, however when you perform the `git pull` it requests a username and password.  I want to inject my username, and then type the password myself.  How would I go about doing this?

Current code:

```
git checkout development
git pull
```

Comment: Why don't you [change your git config](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)?  [and saving the password detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git)

Comment: For some reason in my environment at work, this doesn't work.