# Failed to connect to remote repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-remote

I accidentally switched from my remote dev branch to local dev and now I cannot switch back.

When I try to:

```
 git fetch origin/master
```

I get

> fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I also tried:

```
git checkout origin/master
```

And I got:

> error: pathspec 'origin' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>   error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I checked with git remote -v that the url for my origin was there. Also in config file the right url is indicated

```
remote.dev.url=https://'my_origin_url'.git
remote.dev.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev/*
remote.dev.pushurl=https://'my_origin_url.git
branch.dev.remote=dev
branch.dev.merge=refs/heads/dev
remote.origin.url=https://'my_origin_url'.git/
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And I tried:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

The result was:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path
>   not in the working tree.

How can I go back to my origin branch?

Comment: Those two separate `pathspec ...` errors indicate that you must have run `git checkout origin master`. Git can be terribly confusing here: when should you use `origin`, when `master`, when `origin/master`, and when `origin master`? The answers are all different!

Comment: Yes, I probably did run `git checkout origin master` :( can you advise me what should I do next?

Comment: there was problem with connection to remote repo, I resolved it and successfully switched to origin branch, thank you for you advice

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch, you should only specify the remote, not the branch:

```
git fetch origin
```

To checkout master:

```
git checkout master
```

Since it looks like `master` is not already a local branch in your sandbox, it should get automatically recreated with `origin/master` as its upstream, which is what you want.

If it gets created with `dev/master` instead as its upstream, you will need to set its upstream branch explicitly.

Option 1: explicitly specify the upstream when you create the branch:

```
git checkout -b master -t origin/master
```

Option 2: update the upstream after the fact, if the branch exists with the wrong upstream:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

Comment: I get `error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/master' does not exist` for the option 2. And for the option 1 I cannot do fetch either, I get `fatal: unable to access 'https://my_origin_url.git/': Failed connect to my_origin_url:443; Connection refused`

Comment: If `git fetch` fails with a connection refused, you'll need to provide your credentials, the same way you must have had to do when you did the initial `git clone`. You may need to update your ssh key or credentials within the git config. Have a look here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: `Connection refused` looks more like an issue with networking or with the configuration on the remote system. You should be able to see some more detail with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git fetch origin`.