# GitHub Remote: forbidden fatal: unable to access the requested url returned error: 403

Tags: git, github, version-control

Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.

I tried using github desktop, command line, git bash and via azure devops too, nothing seems to be working. I have an individual account and I am the owner, so I don't think I shouldn't have access. I can't push or fetch. 
Attaching screenshots below - 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to clone your repo and it works fine.

Did you try to check this help from GitHub https://help.github.com/en/articles/https-cloning-errors ?

You might have to enter your github credentials or store them correctly - or provide a token if you have 2FA enabled.

Comment: Store GitHub credentials where? Sorry, I'm new with GitHub and using visual studio 2017/command line.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: Just FYI - My organization has blocked public repos'.

Comment: @WriteTheCode Did you find what was going wrong. I can clone the repo find but I can't push my branch. I'm getting the same error as you. :(