# When I type git config --list my user.password is also showing in plain text

Tags: git, github, terminal

How can I hide or not show user.password when I type git config --list in my terminal.

Comment: Try using git credentials https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command on a Unix-like terminal:

```
git config --list | grep -v "user.password"
```

Comment: I can still see user.password with my password in plain text

Comment: This is very strange since `grep -v` hides all lines containing the string `user.password`. Which shell are you using (cygwin/linux/unix)?

Answer (score 1):

You can only avoid your password being shown by not entering it into the git config in the first place. As @EncryptedWatermelon suggested, try out [git credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git).

The `grep -v` only filters the output of your command and does not alter your actual configuration file. If you enter `git config --list` again afterwards, the password will still be there. Unfortunately, `git config --list` always outputs your entire git config and there is **nothing you can do about that**.