# Pushing to Github prompts for password to incorrect url

Tags: git

Not sure exactly what this did but now when I try to push, I get

```
Password for 'https://--global@github.com':
```

previous to the problem of the url now having `--global` in it which is incorrect I had run this command:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git config credential.username "dsmith"
git config credential.user --global "dsmith"
git config credential.email --global "dsmith@gmail.com"
```

so that must have screwed things up.  I want to fix this, not sure how.  I have no idea how this messed up the github url and put --global in it, I thought the above were legit commands.

I at least set it back to using the oskeychain as the helper

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Comment: the global needs to be before the credentials `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git`

Comment: err that's what I figured, crap

Comment: `git config credential.user --global "dsmith"` will set the username to --global, and then ignore your username. Mistakes where made

Comment: I updated it now with `git config --global  credential.user "dsmith"` but it still shows  'https://--global@github.com'

Comment: also I understand that credential.user is not the same as your git username?

Comment: that is true, the credentials is what you use when pushing a commit/logging into github, while your username is what declare who did each commit.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this one-line code:

```
git config --global credential.username "dsmith"
```