# Git prompting for username and password for every git command

Tags: git, github, windows-10, github-enterprise

I have generated a personal access token for github enterprise. I have also updated in windows credential manager. However whevever I run any git command from git bash in windows 10, it prompts for username and password.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git-gitextension

Answer (score 0):

If Git prompts you for a username and password every time you try to interact with GitHub, you're probably using the HTTPS clone URL for your repository. Using an HTTPS remote URL has some advantages: it's easier to set up than SSH, and usually works through strict firewalls and proxies.

Comment: I know that, how can I store the personal ccess token as password, so it never prompts me again and again with username and password?