# Configure Gitlab account to Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am using Visual Studio Code and working locally in a repository that is in Gitlab, but every time I use the command  `git push origin master` I get a pop window to enter my Gitlab account and password. My question is there any form to configure my Gitlab account so I do not need to enter my credentials every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this answer to know how to save your username and password for git in a secure way so that it doesn't ask you again and again.

[How to save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git)

Also as you mentioned about VSCode, there are many extensions that helps you with handling git but one of those which I will recommend is GitLens. As it will also let you know who changed which part of code.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. GitLens really help me also a lot.