# Separating the git credentials for two different git accounts

Tags: git

I am using `Github` for the ***personal*** repositories and `GitLab` for the ***companies team*** repositories.

Thanks to [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git), I was able to separate personal repositories with the work repositories (in the context of git account info) like below `gitconfig` script.

However, I still couldn't separate the **`git credentials`**. Thus, I have to write ids and passwords every time they are required. Can someone help me separating the git credentials by the working directory for two different git accounts like the below config files?

`~/.gitconfig`

```sh
[user]
        email = personal@gmail.com
        name = My Name

[includeIf "gitdir:~/repositories/work/"]
        path = ~/repositories/work/.gitconfig
```

`~/repositories/work/.gitconfig`

```sh
[user]
        email = MyName@company.com
        name = My Name
```

p.s. My setting is git 2.25.x and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: why don't you use ```git config --local``` https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe the local option is for each repository not for the whole repositories under the specified directory (like `./work/`).

Comment: by git credentials, do you mean username and password that are required when you push via https to remote repo? if yes, why don't you just use ssh keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up separating the `git config` files and `git credentials` as below. The below setting ables me to separate all repositories' credentials from that of under `work/` directory.

(Didn't know that `.git-credentials` automatically handles it by appending the credentials in plain text.) Thanks.

1. `~/.gitconfig`

```sh
[user]
        email = personal@gmail.com
        name = My Name

[includeIf "gitdir:~/repositories/work/"]
        path = ~/repositories/work/.gitconfig

[credential]
        helper = store
```

2. `~/repositories/work/.gitconfig`

```sh
[user]
        email = MyName@company.com
        name = My Name

[credential]
        # (or) helper = cache --timeout 86400
        helper = store
```