# Git always ask for my credentials although my credentials are inside .gitconfig

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I stored my credentials inside `~/.gitconfig` using the following commands:

```
git config --global user.name "MauroTheCreator"
git config --global user.email "myemail@gmail.com"
```

But when I commit data to a branch and push the data, it take my credentials again

I commit using

```
git add stuff
git commit
git push
```

This is really anoying, how can i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git)

Comment: What you've set in `.gitconfig` is the metadata to add to the `git commit`s you make. That is **not** the same thing as the credentials to use for requests to `git push` to the remote (e.g. BitBucket, GitHub, GitLab).

Answer (score 1):

Git uses `credential helpers` behind the scene to store your credentials.
You can check which credential-helper is configured on your system by running `git config --list` and lookin up for `credential.helper` or by just running `git config credential.helper`.

On windows, older versions of git(before Git 2.29) use [Git Credential Manager For Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) and have default helper set as `credential.helper=manager` whereas, newer Git releases( Git 2.29 or later) use [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) and have the default helper configured as `credential.helper=manager-core`.

I don't have any experience working with OSX, but as far as the online sources say, the `git config credential.helper` returns `credential.helper=osxkeychain`.

You can tell git to store credentials by running the `git credential approve` command followed by key-value pairs of protocol, host, username and password :

```
git credential approve
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=<user-name>
password=<pwd/token>
Hit RETURN/ENTER key Twice
```

Your credentials should now be saved.

You can confirm that by running `git fill` command:

```
git credential fill
protocol=https
host=github.com
Hit RETURN/ENTER Key twice
```

Running the above should return the credentials.
I have a windows system. But since git's commands should work almost the same on any OS, this should work fine on Mac as well.