# git commit and push to branch with password using sh file

Tags: git, github, commit, credentials

I am trying, with a sh file, to commit my changes, enter my git credentials, and push the changes to the branch I'm working on. I can't get the credentials part to work

```
#!/bin/sh
cd pathtomyrepo
git add *.py
git commit -m "made changes"
git push origin mybranch
mygitusername
echo Press Enter...
mygitpassword
echo Press Enter...
```

note: I had to run this `chmod +x pathtomyshscript.sh` beforehand to be able to run the sh file.

The error I get is:

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
> fatal: failed to write commit object

Which I presume mean that my credentials were not passed to git.
Any suggestion on how to do it? Is it even possible at all?

Comment: I see 2 major mistakes here. 1st, the error is not from push, it's from an earlier local command. To find out which on run `sh -x ./pathtomyshscript.sh` — shell will echo each command before executing.

Comment: 2nd, you cannot pass credentials like this from your shell. When `git push` asks for credentials it stucks, the shell script is not going on and your `echo` commands do not run. There are many different ways to properly pass credentials — credential manager, login/password in HTTPS URL, SSH keypair in SSH URL.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I modified the code to fix the 1st problem and will look into the solutions you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Registering the SSH key may indirectly solve your issue. If you must use HTTPS with the script, then please use a password manager ! Copy-pasting your details inside a script is **highly** discouraged.

For macOS, you can use the Keychain to get and set your Git password:

```
GIT_PASSWORD=$(security find-generic-password -w -s '<Service Name>' -a '<account>')
```

Now, I must warn that blindly `add`'ing and `commit`'ing to a repo is **not** good practice!

Instead, you may look up `git alias` for shorthands and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git) for `git credentials`