# Github contributions not showing up but emails match

Tags: github

My Github contributions aren't being tracked when I commit from the command line and I can't figure out why.

My `git config user.email` and `git config --global user.email` and my primary email on Github all match.

However, when I went on the github site and deleted a file from a PR through the GUI, and committed it, that showed up as a contribution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, after doing that, I assume that commit is now on the default branch?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple possibilities:

- You haven't pushed them to GitHub.
- Your changes aren't in the main repository, but a fork.
- Your changes aren't in the default branch.

GitHub has [documentation on the reasons this can happen](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile).

Comment: 1. I have pushed them to github
2. The changes are on a branch that has an open PR to the main repo

Why would my commit that I pushed from the github website show up in my contributions but not those from the command line?

Comment: If your contributions are not merged into the main branch (that is, they're just in a PR), then they don't count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `git push` command to push the changes to the repository on GitHub. Otherwise, the changes will take effect in your local repository.

```
# After making changes to the local repository, use the command below to monitor all those changes.
git add .

# Use the command below to commit all changes.
git commit -m "Message"

# Run the following command for the changes to take effect in the repository on GitHub:
git push -u origin feature
# If your branch name is "main" use it like this:
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: I have been pushing them and they still dont show up :(

Comment: After you create the project on github, pull it to your local. This way the remote connection is set up correctly. Then, when you follow the steps I mentioned above, the changes will be applied to your GitHub account.

Comment: If there is a problem with authorization follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git).

Comment: To check authorization, in Windows 10, go to `Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager`. In this field `git:https://github.com` **must have the correct username and password**.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Alternatively, start a project in VS Code and try to push through the interface to upload it to the remote repository. Getting the right authorization can help you indirectly through this process.

Answer (score 0):

If your `git config user.email` and `git config --global user.email` and your primary email on Github all match. Then the issue might be because of the below suggestion.

After making a commit that meets the requirements to count as a contribution, you may need to wait for up to 24 hours to see the contribution appear on your contributions graph.

Got this from the [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commit-was-made-less-than-24-hours-ago)