# Is it possible to store github credentials (on a remote server) limited to specific repository or organisation?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to deal with the following security vs DX issue:

- I'm working on a project where code is stored on GitHub and I have to sometimes deploy backend on a server
- I don't want to type GitHub credentials for each pull or other operation
- since some other team members have access to the `root` user, I don't want to store creds in a way others can use those to access arbitrary repo of mine (not only those of that project)

Now, as far as I know, I have 2 options to connect to GitHub from server these days:

1. SSH: create key, add to ssh-agent, add public key to GitHub account, use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:account/repo.git`
2. PAT: create a GitHub token, use at as a password, store it via `git config --global credential.helper store` or `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'` or (as [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) suggests GitHub CLI Git Credential Manager)

The problem is, they all seem to have either drawback:

- give `root` user access to all my github repos (they can simply do `sudo su - username` and access) or
- require me to type some passphrase each time or
- a mixture of the 2: caching with timeout allows not to type creds for some time, but in that period they also have unlimited access to other repos

For instance, I either protect my ssh key with passphrase and will have to type it or don't protect it and the access is unlimited. Using PAT a bit more limited access (for instance, I can [give PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (see 8.) only access to `repo` actions and not various `admin` action, but still I can't limit it to specific repo or organisation.

Am I missing some option here? I've reviewed more or less all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/3995261) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35942754/3995261) but haven't noticed any solution.

Note: I'm using SSH to do CLI operations on the server.

Comment: The best way is to do this with CI/CD tools. But, is it possible to mount the server directory in your local machine. Then you can do copy and paste or something like that

Comment: @MarkusMeyer sounds reasonable, thanks for the suggestion. I think I'll look into some tutorial like [this one](https://dev.to/chathula/how-to-set-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-node-js-app-with-github-actions-32h0) (current project does not use Kubernetes, so GitOps is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deploy code for a specific repository is to use [a deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys).  This is an SSH key that's associated with a repository instead of a user, and has access only to the contents of that repository.  The access can be either read-only or read-write.

That article also discusses server-to-server tokens, which are like a PAT, but can be restricted to a single repository and are also a possibility in this situation.

Comment: sounds great, I'll look into this, thanks!