# How setup credentials in Git Credential Manager on Linux?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I'm new to using Gitlab. My workplace has recently moved from on-prem Git to a cloud-based Gitlab host. I used ssh authentication in the past with our on-prem so never had to deal with credentials hanging around (I'm using Linux) in `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig`.

If I let `git` manage my credentials/tokens, with whatever defaults it uses, those creds/tokens end up stored in plaintext in my home directory under `~/.git-credentials` or in the `.git/config` file, which is problematic for various reasons.

I poked around and found [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.blog/2020-07-02-git-credential-manager-core-building-a-universal-authentication-experience/) but after getting it installed, as shown in the [README](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager), I'm not exactly sure it's working correctly, or I'm misunderstanding how to use it. I ran these commands to get it setup:

- `dpkg -i gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb`
- `git-credential-manager-core configure`
- `git config --global credential.credentialStore gpg`
- `pass init <gpg-id>`

I tried cloning a cloud-based repo using a personal access token, but when I clone it, `gpg` prompts me for my passphrase, but the token ends up in the `.git/config file` anyway.

```
$ git clone https://user-test-token:glpat-w1...xp@gitlabhost.com/my.username/my-repo.git
$ cat .git/config
...
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://user-test-token:glpat-w1...xp@gitlabhost.com/my.username/my-repo.git
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git)

Comment: Why not continue to use SSH based authentication?

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes not really.  Anything using `credential.helper` is going to store things in the clear (as far as I can tell). Also, some of those posts mention _just put your credentials in the URL_ which also gets saved in `.git/config` in cleartext also.

Comment: @fredrik our business unit was merged with another entity and this is how it works now.

Comment: @Nstevens "Anything using credential.helper is going to store things in the clear": That has not been my experience on Windows, where it is stored in the Windows Valut (the windows Credential Manager). And Linux should have an equivalent (possibly https://www.passwordstore.org/). You could even use setup netrc as a possible way to encrypt your credentials: [I have done so back in the days, -- pre-GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309).

Comment: I think what @fredrik mean is to add a ssh-key to https://<gitlab-host>/-/profile/keys

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes True, however the question is for HTTPS credentials management.

Answer (score 2):

Check if this is a [TTY issue](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#headlesstty-only-sessions)

> If you are using the gpg credential store in a headless/TTY-only environment, you must ensure you have configured the GPG Agent (`gpg-agent`) with a suitable pin-entry program for the terminal such as `pinentry-tty` or `pinentry-curses`.
>
> If you are not connecting via SSH, or otherwise do not have the `SSH_TTY` environment variable set, you must set the `GPG_TTY` environment variable before running GCM.
> The easiest way to do this is by adding the following to your profile (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` etc):
>
> ```
> export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good catch but I'm not running headless. I _do_ get the `pinentry-curses` prompt and `SSH_TTY` is currently set to `/dev/pts/2`. I'm reading up on the `pass` utility. I think there's more that I need to do there and it just isn't documented in the GCM info.

Comment: @Nstevens I agree, https://www.passwordstore.org/ would be your best bet if you are not in an headless environment.

Answer (score 2):

In your git clone command, you inserted a personal access token into the remote URL. This is insecure and prevents Git from calling any configured credential helpers. Instead, you should clone with the unadorned remote URL.

Next, **Git Credential Manager only supports gitlab.com out the box** (see [GitLab issue #374172](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/)). To use with another GitLab instance such as `gitlab.example.com`, follow the instructions at https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/gitlab.md .

---

For what it's worth, you might find it easier to use [git-credential-oauth](https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-oauth), included in [many Linux distributions](https://repology.org/project/git-credential-oauth/versions) including [Fedora](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/git-credential-oauth/git-credential-oauth/), [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/git-credential-oauth) and [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/git-credential-oauth).