# How to set up credentials in a config file?

Tags: github

Shown below is piece of code for git push. Every time when I am running the push command, it's prompting to enter the Username and Password. Is there a way to make GitHub pick the credentials from a file?

```
vboxuser@Ubuntu-20:~/git-repo/terraform-AWS$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': xxxx
Password for 'https://conanl@github.com':
```

Comment: Can you [use SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git)