# How can I force my console to open git credentials again?

Tags: git, console, clone, access-token

I tried to clone a repo and typed in my username and access-token as password. Accidentally, I typed the wrong password in. Now when I try to clone again, the popup asking for my credentials is not showing anymore, instead it instantly says: "*Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect ...*"

I tried restarting my computer, but that did not solve the problem.

How I can force to open the window where I can type in my credentials again?

Comment: Run `git config credential.helper` to find out which helper is being used. The helper is a program or a file. You can edit the username and password.

Comment: @ElpieKay your command has no output in my console. I found on web to try `git config --system --unset credential.helper`. This works, but now I always need to type in my username and password. How can I get back to normal? :/

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git. It mentions several helpers like `store`, `cache`. If you use windows, `manager` is also an option. An alternative is to use ssh urls instead of https urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and run this command `git config --global --edit` 
Locate the `credential.helper` and change the `credential.helper` value to `cache --timeout=1`

```
[credential]
helper = cache --timeout=1
```

Save and close the file. Try to perform a Git action that requires authentication, such as pushing or pulling from a remote repository.

If you want to completely disable Git credential caching, you can set the

```
[credential]
helper = store
```