# How to best set credentials to clone a repo with submodules?

Tags: git, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to clone a repository--which contains submodules--onto a Windows machine. Previously we were cloning it with something like this:

```
git clone https://[username]:[password]@myServer.com/bitbucket/scm/[project]/[repo].git
```

This was working fine until we started adding submodules to this repo and using and `git clone --recurse-submodules`. Now once it gets to the point of pulling in the submodules it's throwing errors that the logon session doesn't exist, I *believe* it's because the credentials were only passed once via the parent repo URL and not actually configured in the git config.

So I've tried a few different methods to remedy this:

1. Use the `ansible.builtin.git` module.

As it turns out, this module isn't supported for Windows machines (despite that not being mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html)).

2. Set the credentials using Windows Credential Manager.

This led to various issues, ultimately because `community.windows.win_credential` must be run with `become: true` and the account doesn't have `SeAllowLogonLocally` (which is very strange, because the account is in the local `Administrators` group, and that group has the `Allow log on locally` right in the local security policy).

3. Set the credentials using `git config`.

I tried using these commands:

```
git config --global credential.https://myServer.com.username {{ username }}
git config --global credential.https://myServer.com.password {{ password }}
```

I logged in and verified that the username/password are configured in `~\.gitconfig` for that site, but I still received these errors:

> fatal: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated
> git: 'credential-winscred' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://[username]@myServer.com': No such file or directory

I feel like I'm running into a new issue at every turn. So have any of you been able to successfully clone a repo with submodules? How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942890/22146392) for helping me find the solution:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git clone --recurse-submodules https://[username]:[password]@myServer.com/bitbucket/scm/[project]/[repo].git
```

Setting the credential helper to `store` saved the credentials from the initial clone and they were able to be used to pull in the submodules.