# git status fatal: unable to access 'C:\jbase5\home;C:\xampp\php;/.config/git/config': Invalid argument

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Every time I try to launch my *SourceTree* application I get this error popup:

[image: Source tree error notification]

If I try to use my git from the command line I get the same error

[image: git command line error]

So far I have tried to check my environment variables but there's no path variable with errors.

Comment: What does `where git` and `git version` state?

Comment: Thank you Eric found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution right after posting this question... Thank you all. #muchlove

[SOlved Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736191/fatal-unable-to-access-h-config-git-config-invalid-argument-git-on-windo?rq=1)